# Json properties grouped with regex

Tags: json, regex, node.js

I'm trying to define a json file in which I have some properties(a lot) with the same values, my goal is to define only a property with the name as a regex that match all my needed properties with same values.

It's possible to label a property as a regex and then import the json file in node, with all the properties splited??

This are properties sample:

```
   "T700": {
     "statusCode": 500,
     "devmsg": "Authentication failed. Server error."   },
   "T701": {
     "statusCode": 500,
     "devmsg": "Internal Server Error"   },   
   "T702": {
     "statusCode": 500,
     "devmsg": "Internal Server Error"   },
```

And the goal should be:

```
"^(T7[0-2][0-9])": {
 "statusCode": 500,
 "devmsg": "Authentication failed. Server error."   },
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: And once you have the desired result, then you don't need the previous keys for example ``T700``,``T701`` etc?

Comment: What is the criteria used to split attributes ? is it ``statusCode`` ?

Comment: The properties are splitted based on the regex